# Exact functors between triangulated categories

Tags: solution-verification, category-theory, triangulated-categories

If I have two triangulated categories $\mathcal{D},\mathcal{D}'$ with shift functors $T_{\mathcal{D}},T_{\mathcal{D}'}$, then for an exact functor $F \colon \mathcal{D}\to\mathcal{D}'$ by definition there exists a natural isomorphism $F\circ T_{\mathcal{D}}\cong T_{\mathcal{D}'}\circ F$. How I can prove that there exists a natural isomorphism $F\circ T^{-1}_{\mathcal{D}}\cong T^{-1}_{\mathcal{D}'}\circ F$?

My attempt is the following:

Let $\eta \colon F\circ T_{\mathcal{D}}\xrightarrow{\sim} T_{\mathcal{D}'}\circ F$ be the natural isomorphism. Then we can define for all $A$ “the composition” $T_{\mathcal{D}'}^{-1}\circ \eta_A\circ T_{\mathcal{D}}^{-1} \colon T_{\mathcal{D}'}^{-1}(F(A))\to F(T_{\mathcal{D}}^{-1}(A))$
and this collection of morphisms defines the sought natural isomorphism. The naturality corresponds for a morphism $f:A\to B$ to
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
T_{\mathcal{D}'}^{-1}(F(A)) @>{\enspace T_{\mathcal{D}' \enspace}^{-1}(F(f))}>> T_{\mathcal{D}'}^{-1}(F(B))\\
@VVV @VVV\\
F(T_{\mathcal{D}}^{-1}(A)) @>{\enspace F(T_{\mathcal{D}}^{-1}(f)) \enspace}>> F(T_{\mathcal{D}}^{-1}(A))
\end{CD}
and the commutativity of this diagram is direct by the naturality of $\eta$ applied in the corresponding objects. Also, this natural transformation is an isomorphism because every $\eta_A$ is an isomorphism and then $T_{\mathcal{D}'}^{-1}\circ \eta_A\circ T_{\mathcal{D}}^{-1}$ is an isomorphism too. I would appreciate feedback on this.

Comment: What have you tried? Alternatively, what is the context behind this problem; where did you find it, and what relevant knowledge do you have?

Comment: I've added the proof that I have written, I would like to have an opinion on it.

Comment: The context behind this problem is pretty obvious to absolutely anyone who knows what the words used mean, really...